# How can I preserve the log upon a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, logging, preserve, browser-console

In Google Chrome is it possible to preserve the log onto a new tab when opened?

I know the preserve log option will save the logs text upon navigation, but I want to make it so the log is copied over to the new tab so each new tab will have the same JavaScript, any ideas?

Comment: Which web browser are you using? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Im using chrome